# How to access my public IP from LAN

Tags: networking, router, ip, iptables, dd-wrt

I'm currently using a Netgear router with DD-WRT firmware.

I have a laptop with a camera application installed. The application uses public address and ports to operate the cameras. When I'm at work, the app works fine, but at home it does not. At home I have to change the configuration by changing the IP address to private. However, at work I have to change the IP address to public. And I do it over and over again.

The case looks like this:

```
                    +-----------------+     +------------------+
                    | Camera 01       |     | Camera 02        |
                    | 192.168.1.10:80 |     | 192.168.1.11:80  |
                    | from port: 8081 |     | from port: 8082  |
                    +-----------------+     +------------------+
                                       \   /
                                        \ /
+-------------+       +------------------+-----------------+
|     ISP     |---/---| Router (WAN port)| Router(local IP)|
| 128.x.x.107 |       | 192.168.10.1     | 192.168.1.1     |
+-------------+       +------------------+-----------------+
```

- I can access the cameras on my computer from outside (eg from work), using the public IP address, eg entering 128.x.x.107: 8081.
- I can also access cameras from the LAN by entering 192.168.1.10.
- Unfortunately, I can not access the cameras from the LAN using the public IP address 128.x.x.107: 8081. Does anyone have an idea how to do it?

I've read a lot about NAT loopback / reflection / hairpinning, but I do not understand it well enough to deal with my problem.

Using the following rules, I was able to connect to my router via the public ip address from the LAN.

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -d 128.x.x.107 -j DNAT --to 192.168.1.1
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -s 192.168.1.1 -j SNAT --to 128.x.x.107
```

. . .but if in the above rule instead of the router's address (192.168.1.1) I use the camera address (192.168.1.10), it will not work.

Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Nat hairpin needed.

https://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Hairpin_NAT

Basically create a rule that any lan ip going to your server(s) via your wan ip gets rewritten as lan ip <==> lan ip.

I needed that myself on my routers for various things (mail, web, ssh)

Comment: Welcome to Super User! How would they implement that hairpin NAT on their Netgear router? OP already said they know about hairpin NAT but not enough to implement it, so expanding on your answer would be useful :)

Comment: @AndrewSchott thank you for the answer. I've seen this wiki before. The problem is that I can not convert mikrotik rules to iptables rules. I'm just starting to learn how to configure a firewall so please if you can expand your answer...

Comment: Sorry, im still at work, but does this work : "iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i <local interface> -s <internal ip range> -d <external ip of server> -p tcp --dport 8081 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.1" ?

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work. Returns the message "Connection failed" :(